# Robotjs error: Invalid key code specified

Tags: javascript, json, substring

I have the following code in index.js

```
var settingsFile = "config.json";


var settings = JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(settingsFile));

const net = require('net');
const robot = require("robotjs");
const fs = require("fs");

var client;

var customKeys = {
    "scroll_up":'robot.scrollMouse(50, "up");',
    "scroll_down":"robot.scrollMouse(50,'down');"

}

function startCommunication(address,port) {

    client = net.connect({port: port,host:address}, () => {
        // 'connect' listener
        console.log('connected to server!');
        //client.write('world!\r\n');
    });
    client.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
        var string = data.toString();
        console.log(settings.keys[string.substr(1)]);
        if(string.substr(0,1) == "d") {
            robot.keyToggle(settings.keys[string.substr(1)],"down");
        } else {
            robot.keyToggle(settings.keys[string.substr(1)],"up");
        }

        //client.end();
    });
    client.on('end', () => {
        console.log('disconnected from server');
    });
}

startCommunication(settings.address,settings.port);
```

i also have this code in config.json, aka what is parsed into the settings variable.

```
{
    "port":5555,

    "address":"192.168.1.118",

    "keys":{
        "KEY_A":"a",
        "KEY_B":"b",
        "KEY_X":"x",
        "KEY_Y":"y",
        "KEY_L":"y",
        "KEY_R":"t",
        "KEY_DUP":"up",
        "KEY_DDOWN":"down",
        "KEY_DLEFT":"left",
        "KEY_DRIGHT":"right",
        "KEY_START":"z",
        "KEY_SELECT":"q"
    }
}
```

What The Problem is is that when i get down to either robotjs.togglekeys statement i get the error

```
Error: Invalid key code specified.
```

This means that, as there error clearly states, it is getting an invalid keycode. I am guessing that is is some stupid mistake that I made. data in my testing is equal to "dKEY_DRIGHT". the variable string is equal to that but i need to get rid of the d in order for it to work. when i do the live console i am able to get the data that I need by using the same code but somethig goes wrong when it is being ran in the file. anything helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Old issue, but maybe someone else is searching for a solution like me...

If you don't have any modifiers pressed you should pass as modifier the string "none". I was passing an empty string, this caused the same issue.
This at least worked for me, even though it its an optional parameter.

https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#keytogglekey-down-modifier

```
robot.keyToggle(settings.keys[string.substr(1)],"down","none");
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try using node-key-sender to send keys presses to your operational system.

Install it with `npm install --save-dev node-key-sender`.

And send a key to the keyboard using:

```
var ks = require('node-key-sender');
ks.sendKey('up');
```

All the values of you config ('a', 'b', ...) are accepted by the lib. You can send them directly.

Check the documentation page for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender.